# Push-forward Fisher information

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, parametric, radon-nikodym, fisher-information

Let $(P_\theta)_{\theta\in\Theta}$ be a family of probability distributions on some measurable space $\mathcal X$, where $\Theta$ is some open real interval. Let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathcal X$ that dominates all the $P_{\theta}$'s (let us assume that such a $\nu$ exists). 
For each $\theta\in\Theta$, let $f(\cdot,\theta)$ be a density of $P_\theta$ with respect to $\nu$, and assume that for $\nu$-almost all $x\in\mathcal X$, $f(x,\cdot)$ is differentiable (as a function of $\theta$).

Now, let $\phi$ be a measurable function from $\mathcal X$ to some other measurable space $\mathcal Y$. Denote by $\mu$ the push-forward of $\nu$ by $\phi$, and by $Q_\theta$ the push-forward of $P_\theta$ by $\phi$, for all $\theta\in\Theta$.

Is it true that for all $\theta$, $Q_\theta$ has a density $g(\cdot,\theta)$ with respect to $\mu$ such that $g(y,\cdot)$ is differentiable for $\mu$-almost all $y\in\mathcal Y$?

The reason why I'm asking is that I would like to prove rigorously that if a parametric model has a Fisher information, then the push-forward model also has a well-defined Fisher information.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use the co-area formula, as was done here https://mathoverflow.net/a/165421/78539

Comment: @dohmatob, here I do not assume that the function $\phi$ (in the post that you pointed out, it is denoted by $\pi$) is linear, or even smooth. It is just any measurable function...